# netlogo - trouble with exiting while loop when condition is false

Tags: while-loop, netlogo

I have a list of ordered patches `x`, and I ask each of these patches to find the patches within a certain radius of themselves (this resulting list is called `x_radius`). I basically want to iterate through each `x` and then the corresponding patches in `x_radius` (taking the first item in `x` and then taking that item's first item in `x_radius` etc) and check if a patch variable `food` for a given `x_radius` patch is equal to or less than .5 (here I have it set to a random number for simplicity). If it is greater than .5, I would like to stop the loop. So, what I am thinking the order of commands to achieve this should be is:

1. Ask 1st patch in `x` to find patches in radius
2. Ask 1st patch in `x_radius` of the 1st patch in `x` to find their food amount
3. If their `food` amount is <= .5, ask the 2nd patch in `x_radius` of the 1st patch in `x` to find their `food`
4. Repeat until any patch in any `x_radius` of any `x` patch is > .5

This is a simplified bit of the code I am working on:

```
        foreach x [p ->  
          ask p [
           set x_radius patches in-radius 5
            while [all? x_radius [food <= .5]] [ 
             foreach x_radius [n ->
              ask n [
                set food random-float 1.0]
                 ]
                  ]
                    ]
```

I see that the while loop is not exiting when the one of the `x_radius` patches to be evaluated has food. The code basically goes through all of the `x` patches without evaluating the `x_radius` patches, so somewhere my logic is messy. I've always had some trouble with while loops; I have a feeling it is because `food` is set within the while loop, but I am referencing it before? Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

UPDATE: The following code gets me closer to what I want, however, if an `x_radius` patch has a negative `food` value, the code keeps evaluating that same patch over and over again, when I would want to move on to the next `x_radius` patch. Do-calculations is a dummy function that calculates some value:

```
        foreach x [p ->  
          ask p [
           set x_radius patches in-radius 5
           set food 0
             foreach sort x_radius [n ->
                while [food <= .5] [
              ask n [
                set food do-calculations]
                 ]
                  ]
                    ]
                     ]
                      ]
```

Comment: Not clear when you want the loop to stop (can you clarify point 4?) and what you want to do at every iteration of the loop. What your current code does: check if EVERY SINGLE PATCH in `x_radius` has `food <= 0.5`. If that is the case, ask EVERY SINGLE PATCH in `x_radius` to randomly set a new `food` value. Then check again the condition of EVERY SINGLE PATCH in `x_radius` having `food <= 0.5`. Setting values randomly, the chance that every patch in a radius of 5 has `food <0.5` is EXTREMELY LOW. Is that really the condition that you want to test, and those the actions that you want to perform?

Comment: @Matteo No! That does sound very off. I do not want to set a patch's food to anything (looking at that part of the code now, I realize it is very wrong). I am basically just trying to find which `x_radius` patch has a food value > .5, but I want to do this by iterating through the `x_radius` patches of the `x` patches. So the order of checking the food values would be: 1) Patch 1 of `x`, patch 1 of `x_radius` of patch 1 of `x` 2) Patch 1 of `x`, patch 2 of `x_radius` of patch 1 of `x` etc ... Once I find that an `x_radius` patch has a food value greater than .5, I want to exit the whole loop.

Comment: @Matteo I added an update to the code bit that shows where I am. In the previous comment, I should've said that I want to set a patch's food to a value determined by some equation, and then check the value and see if it's >.5. Sorry for the confusion.